C++ Rectangle 2D Array with numbers beside the rectangle
I've been trying to make a 2D array of rectangle, and i want the number of index x to printed beside the rectangle and index y to be printed below the rectangle..
Here is my code..
int height, width;

cout << "Enter height value: ";
cin >> height;
cout << endl << "Enter width value: ";
cin >> width;

for (int i = 0; i < height + 2; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width + 2; j++)
    {
        if (i == 0 || i == height + 1|| j == 0 || j == width + 1) 
        {
            cout << "# ";
        }
        else
        {
            if (j == 0)
            {
                cout << (height - i % 10);
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " " ;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}

i know the problem is that this j has to be == -1 to be printed out beside which is not possible, or is there any other logical way to do it?
What i got:

This is the desired output:


Please also show the output you get instead and turn the shown code into a [mre].

Why is printing before the inner loop not an option? Maybe even before and after the outer loop. Try printing different symbols/numbers before the first for and between first and second for and after the last shown }.

Or to put it differently, try cout << endl << (height  - i); instead of current cout << endl; and explain what keeps you from going that way.

Break the problem down. You have to print in order 1) a line of #, 2) a block of numbers followed by two #, 3) another line of #, 4) a line of numbers. Write separate loops for each of these items. You don't have to write the whole program as one big for loop. Apart from anything else breaking the problem down lets you solve the whole problem in stages, which makes things much easier. You have four smaller problems, instead of one big problem.

change the first j == 0 to j == 1?

You can also first fill a 2D array with characters on the correct positions and then print that 2D array. This will avoid a lot of complexity and if/then/else code. First "draw" the top line into the 2D array ... etc.. etc.. (Be aware you will need to dynamically allocate the 2D array, using std::vector<std::vector>`)

My general technique for printing graphics to the console is to just pre-allocate a 2-d array of characters and "print" to that before printing to the console.
In this case, declare a vector of strings. Each string is a row to be printed. Then compute the sizes needed for padding, spacing, and accomodating the row/col index strings.
Below is a bit raw with respect to that each step needs to account for paddings and two-chars per item on row, +/- one logic, etc... But it works.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


// given a width or height length, get the number of characters needed to contain a value up to (len-1)
size_t getPaddingForDim(size_t len) {
    if (len == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    size_t longest = len - 1;
    int padding = 0;
    while (longest != 0) {
        padding++;
        longest /= 10;
    }
    return padding;
}


void printRectangle(size_t width, size_t height) {

    // adjust dims for border
    size_t adjHeight = height + 2;
    size_t adjWidth = width + 2;

    size_t rowPadding = getPaddingForDim(height);
    size_t colPadding = getPaddingForDim(width);
    size_t printWidth = rowPadding + adjWidth * 2;
    size_t printHeight = colPadding + adjHeight;

    std::vector<std::string> rect;

    // initialize our canvas with all spaces
    rect.resize(printHeight);
    for (auto& row : rect) {
        row.resize(printWidth);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < printWidth; i++) {
            row[i] = ' ';
        }
    }

    auto& toprow = rect[0];
    auto& bottomrow = rect[adjHeight - 1];

    // draw horizontal borders
    for (size_t col = 0; col < adjWidth; col++) {
        toprow[rowPadding+col*2] = ' ';
        toprow[rowPadding + col * 2 + 1] = '#';

        bottomrow[rowPadding + col * 2] = ' ';
        bottomrow[rowPadding + col * 2 + 1] = '#';
    }

    // draw vertical borders
    for (size_t row = 0; row < adjHeight; row++) {
        rect[row][rowPadding+1] = '#';
        rect[row][rowPadding + (adjWidth - 1) * 2 + 1] = '#';
    }

    // row numbers
    for (size_t rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < height; rowIndex++) {
        size_t rowvalue = height - 1 - rowIndex;
        std::string s = std::to_string(rowvalue);
        auto& row = rect[rowIndex + 1];

        // print the number from right to left so it will be right aligned
        for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
            char c = s[s.size() - 1 - i];
            row[rowPadding - 1 - i] = c;
        }
    }

    // col numbers
    for (size_t colIndex = 0; colIndex < width; colIndex++) {
        std::string s = std::to_string(colIndex);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
            auto& row = rect[adjHeight + i];
            row[rowPadding + 2 + colIndex * 2 + 1] = s[i];
        }

    }

    // now print to console
    for (auto& row : rect) {
        std::cout << row << "\n";
    }
}


int main()
{
    printRectangle(22,15);
}

The above prints:
   # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
14 #                                             #
13 #                                             #
12 #                                             #
11 #                                             #
10 #                                             #
 9 #                                             #
 8 #                                             #
 7 #                                             #
 6 #                                             #
 5 #                                             #
 4 #                                             #
 3 #                                             #
 2 #                                             #
 1 #                                             #
 0 #                                             #
   # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
                         0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1


You can use setw to make wide spaces instead of using loops
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    int W = 7;
   int H = 15;
    for (int i=0; i<= H+2; ++i){
        if(1<=i && i<=H+1) std::cout << std::setw(2) << (H-i+1) << std::setw(2) << '#' << std::setw(2*W+4) << '#';
        else {
            std::cout << std::setw(2) << ' ';
            for (int j=0; j<= W+2; ++j) std::cout << std::setw(2) << '#';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << std::setw(6) << 0;
    for (int j=1; j<=W; ++j){
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << j;
    }
}

